# Adding a Collection View and a Table View in the same view controller - Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, tableview, collectionview

I am creating an iPAD app. I need to have a UI Collection View and a table view in the same view controller. (Screen is split in 70% - collection view and 30% table view

What is the best strategy to allow me to do this.

PS: My requirements do not allow me to use a split view

public partial class POSScreen : UIViewController
    {
        UIViewController MainController;

```
    UIViewController SecondaryController;

    UIView MainView;
    UIView SecondaryView;

    /* The Widths */
    nfloat leftSide;
    nfloat rightSide;

    public POSScreen () : base ("POSScreen", null)
    {



    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
    {
        // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();

        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        try {
            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            leftSide = ((nfloat.Parse("65") / nfloat.Parse("100")) * nfloat.Parse( View.Frame.Width.ToString()));
            rightSide = ((nfloat.Parse("35") / nfloat.Parse("100")) * View.Frame.Width);

            MainController = new CategoriesProductsSimpleCollectionViewController();
            SecondaryController = new RightSideItemDetail ();

            (MainController as IViewController).SetCollectionViewFrame (new CoreGraphics.CGRect (0, 40, leftSide, View.Frame.Height));
            (SecondaryController as IViewController).SetCollectionViewFrame (new CoreGraphics.CGRect (View.Frame.Width, 40, rightSide, View.Frame.Height));


            this.Add (this.MainController.View);
            this.Add (this.SecondaryController.View);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine (ex.Message);
        }



    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Does your requirements specifically say "Don't use UISplitViewController" or you have some issues with UISplitViewController?

Comment: Hi,
I needed to have a navigation controller in my app, as in the UI Split view requires to be the root view controller of the app and thus cannot have split view. Yes i know that the master and detail can have their navigation bar items. I did implement the UI Split view but i reached a dead end.

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand what's the problem. If you need to put UICollectionView and UITableView together, just do it and calculate their frames. That's all. Frames specify the X/Y of view borders and you can put these two views just next to each other.

Comment: Yes, i am reaching that same conclusion - See updated code
I am new ios development that's all

Comment: Do you need to add more ViewControllers to your viewController? If not then just add Views(UITableView, UICollectionView)instead ViewControllers(UITableViewController, UICollectionViewController).

Comment: Alright i see what you mean.
Then how should i override GetCell etc methods in the UICollectionView? Or am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Create controller

```
public SomeViewController(UIColor color, CGRect frame) : base("SomeViewController", null)
{
     this.color = color;
     this.frame = frame;
}

public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
     base.ViewDidLoad();

     this.View.BackgroundColor = color;
     this.View.Frame = frame;
}
```

2) In controller that you want sub-controllers:

```
var MainController = new SomeViewController(UIColor.Black, new CGRect(0, 0, 100, 500));
var SecondaryController = new SomeViewController(UIColor.Green, new CGRect(150, 0, 100, 500));

this.AddChildViewController(MainController);
this.AddChildViewController(SecondaryController);
this.Add(this.MainController.View);
this.Add(this.SecondaryController.View);
```

The CGRect I created is just sample. You can calculate right values by using
`UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;`